# Running in SuperDevMode

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I tried `SuperDevMode` however when the URL: `http://localhost:9876/` is accessed

and `Dev Mode On` is clicked, I'm getting this:

```
Can't find any GWT Modules on this page.
```

What could I be missing? I already did

```
$mvn gwt:compile
$mvn gwt:run-codeserver
```

I have these versions in the POM:

```
    <gwt.version>2.5.0</gwt.version>
    <gwt.maven.version>2.5.0</gwt.maven.version>
```

Do I need to update the GWT version or the GWT Maven version?  Or what I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea when running SuperDevMode is:

- Run mvn gwt:run-codeserver
- Run the app web container, Tomcat/Wildfly or GAE (in GAE its just mvn appengine:devserver)

The first one, runs the GWT codeserver responsible in compiling the app from within the bookmarklet. 
The second, is to run the web container, because the app is already compiled, so it can run from within the web container directly

Answer (score 9):

As the page explains, the "Dev Mode On" and "Dev Mode Off" should be added as bookmarks to your browser. You'll then use the bookmark when visiting your GWT app to start a Super Dev Mode session.

I wrote a while back about [how Super Dev Mode works](http://blog.ltgt.net/how-does-gwts-super-dev-mode-work); hopefully that should clarify things for you.

**Update:** note that with GWT 2.7, superdevmode is enabled by default within devmode, so you just launch DevMode "as usual" and it actually uses SuperDevMode under-the-hood, with a "compile on load" hook so you no longer use the bookmarklets. The "compile on load" hook can also be enabled with CodeServer using the `-launcherDir` argument (point it to your *war* folder). Note that in both cases, the `*.nocache.js` will then be overwritten with a script tailored for SuperDevMode, containing the "compile on load" hook; so make sure you clean and recompile before deploying. To get back to "classic" DevMode in GWT 2.7, pass `-nosuperDevMode` to the DevMode.

Comment: I did add "Dev Mode On" to the browser bookmark, clicked it then it complains the same "Cannot find any GWT modules..."

Comment: Did you compile **and deploy** your app with Super Dev Mode support enabled?

Comment: Let me rephrase: has the version deployed to your web server been compiled with the Super Dev Mode hook enabled?

Comment: If `-launcherDir` does not work for you do try the `-war` option. The idea is to install the *compile on load* hook where appropriate.